# replace each occurences of text between delimiter with array values (in php)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want replace each occurences between

```
{{
```

and

```
}}
```

i want use the old_text inside the signs {{ }} for choose the new one,
i've this array:

```
$var["blue"]="ocean";
$var["red"]="fire";
$var["green"]="forest";
```

The text could be:

```
people loves {{blue}} looks {{red}} and enjoy {{green}}
```

should become

```
people loves ocean looks fire and enjoy forest
```

i tryed with preg_replace but with no results:

```
function replaceTags($startPoint, $endPoint, $newText, $source) { 
    $var["blue"]="ocean";
    $var["red"]="fire";
    $var["green"]="forest";

    return preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($startPoint).')(.*)('.preg_quote($endPoint).')#si', 'IDONT-KNOW-WHAT-PUT-HERE', $source);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: sure:function replaceTags($startPoint, $endPoint, $newText, $source) {
   $var["blue"]="ocean";
$var["red"]="fire";
$var["green"]="forest";
    return preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($startPoint).')(.*)('.preg_quote($endPoint).')#si', 'IDONT-KNOW-WHAT-PUT-HERE', $source);
}

Comment: Add this inside the question

Comment: @Thamizhan I've just done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also use `preg_replace_callback` as axiac did, however, here's a simple way to handle it.

```
<?php

// SET OUR DEFAULTS
$var["blue"]="ocean";
$var["red"]="fire";
$var["green"]="forest";

$string = 'people loves {{blue}} looks {{red}} and enjoy {{green}}';


// MAKE A CALLBACK FUNCTION THAT WILL REPLACE THE APPROPRIATE VALUES
$callback_function = function($m) use ($var) {
    return $var[$m[2]];
};


// RUN THE PREG_REPLACE_CALLBACK - CALLING THE FUNCTION
$string = preg_replace_callback('~(\{\{(.*?)\}\})~', $callback_function, $string);


// DYNAMITE
print $string;
```

Appending the `use ($var)` to the function allows us to, well ... use the `$var` in our function.  So all we need to do it use the part it matched inside the braces as the key for the array.  That lets us get the value of the array where the key is, say, `blue` and return that value from our function.

When we run this, it outputs the following:

```
people loves ocean looks fire and enjoy forest
```

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/2GzsoK

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect example for the PHP function [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$var = array(
    'blue'  => 'ocean',
    'red'   => 'fire',
    'green' => 'forest',
);
$template = 'people loves {{blue}} looks {{red}} and enjoy {{green}}';

$text = replaceTags('{{', '}}', $template, $var);


/**
 * Replaces the tags in a string using the provided replacement values.
 *
 * @param string $ldelim       the string used to mark the start of a tag (e.g. '{{') 
 * @param string $rdelim       the string used to mark the end of a tag (e.g. '}}') 
 * @param string $template     the string that contains the tags
 * @param array  $replacements the values to replace the tags
 */
function replaceTags($ldelim, $rdelim, $template, array $replacements)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        // The 'U' flag prevents the .* expression to be greedy
        // and match everything from the first to the last tag
        '#'.preg_quote($ldelim).'(.*)'.preg_quote($rdelim).'#U',
        function (array $matches) use ($replacements) {
            // $matches contains the text pieces that matches the capture groups
            // in the regexp
            // $matches[0] is the text that matches the entire regexp
            // $matches[1] is the first capture group: (.*)
            $key = $matches[1];
            if (array_key_exists($key, $replacements)) {
                // Replace the tag if a replacement value exists in the list
                return $replacements[$key];
            } else {
                // Don't replace the tag if a value is not assigned for it
                return $matches[0];

                // Alternatively, you can return a default placeholder string
                // or return '' to remove the tag completely
            }
        },
        $template
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$string = 'people loves {{blue}} looks {{red}} and enjoy {{green}}';

foreach($var as $key => $val){
    str_replace('{{'.$key.'}}', $val, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: the array $var[] come from a dababase and is very very long, i want just replace the words that the text show ups